# ¿Como ocultar submenus al pasar con el ratón con HTML, CSS y JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

He implementado un menu de navegación y necesito que el contenido de cada menu (que pueden ser otros menu) se colapsen o expandan pasar el mouse por encima.

Actualmente no puedo hacer que eso suceda, si oculto los submenus no puedo hacer que vuelva a aparecer, a continuación dejare el código de los archivos que estoy utilizando.

(al presonar el boton el menu principal se oculta y se muestra, si no se muestra el boton hagan click donde deberia estar y funcionará)

[image: submenus que quiero ocultar]

```js
$('#mostrar-nav').on('click',function(){
 $('nav').toggleClass('mostrar');
})
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #252528;
 padding: 0 1em;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.menu{
 list-style: none;
 line-height: 42px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 width: 15em;
 margin: 2em auto;
}

.menu a{
 color: #ddd;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

.menu a:hover{
 margin-left: 1em;
 --webkit-transition: all .5;
 -o-transition: all .5;
 transition: all .5;
}
.menu li{
 box-shadow: 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 1.5em;
 --webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
}

.menu li:hover{
 box-shadow: 15em 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
}



ul,ol{
 list-style: none;
}
nav{
 position: absolute;
 left: -18em;
 z-index: 20;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 padding-right: .25em;
 padding-top: 3em;
 transition: all .5s;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav.mostrar{
 left: 0;
}


#mostrar-nav{
 background: url(https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwievJbtx-DWAhVBF2MKHRFjC4QQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Ficons8.com%2Ficon%2F17551%2Ftop-menu&psig=AOvVaw3Hz6QlP7BvIPG84vpsQOkF&ust=1507536125997991);
 left: 2em;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 2em;
 width: 40px;
 z-index: 30;
 cursor: pointer;
}

h1{
 text-align: right;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

article{
 padding:.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="mostrar-nav"></div>
 <nav class="mostrar">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu4</a></li>
      </ul>
     <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
    </ul>
   <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu6</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <header>
  <h1>prueba de menu</h1>
 </header>

 <article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 </article>
 <footer>
 </footer>
 <script src="mostrar-nav.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocando los menus y submenus de manera jerárquica (uno dentro del otro, como hijos y no como hermanos) lo hace más sencillo.

Cada `li` puede contener hijos `ul` que corresponden a los submenu de ese item:

```
<li> A
    <ul>
          <li> A.1
                <ul> 
                    <li>A.1.1</li>
                </ul>
           </li> 
     </ul>
</li>
```

por lo tanto detectando los eventos`mouseenter` y `mouseleave` de los `li` puedes hacer aparecer y desaparecer sus hijos `ul` según corresponda

**Probar utilizando** [image: full screen]:

```js
$('li').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown(800);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').slideUp(800);
        }
    );
    
$('#mostrar-nav').on('click',function(){
 $('nav').toggleClass('mostrar');
})
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #252528;
 padding: 0 1em;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.menu{
 list-style: none;
 line-height: 42px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 width: 15em;
 margin: 2em auto;
}

.menu a{
 color: #ddd;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

.menu a:hover{
 margin-left: 1em;
 --webkit-transition: all .5;
 -o-transition: all .5;
 transition: all .5;
}
.menu li{
 box-shadow: 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 1.5em;
 --webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
}

.menu li:hover{
 box-shadow: 15em 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
}



ul,ol{
 list-style: none;
}
nav{
 position: absolute;
 left: -18em;
 z-index: 20;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 padding-right: .25em;
 padding-top: 3em;
 transition: all .5s;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav.mostrar{
 left: 0;
}


#mostrar-nav{
 background: url(https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwievJbtx-DWAhVBF2MKHRFjC4QQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Ficons8.com%2Ficon%2F17551%2Ftop-menu&psig=AOvVaw3Hz6QlP7BvIPG84vpsQOkF&ust=1507536125997991);
 left: 2em;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 2em;
 width: 40px;
 z-index: 30;
 cursor: pointer;
}

h1{
 text-align: right;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

article{
 padding:.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>menu</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="mostrar-nav"></div>
 <nav class="mostrar">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">menu1</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu3</a>
            <ul>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">subsubmenu4</a></li>
      </ul>
           </li>
     <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
   <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">menu6</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <header>
  <h1>prueba de menu</h1>
 </header>

 <article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 </article>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tu analisis me ayudó a poder comprender como funciona, gracas :D